# ¿Cómo configurar mi datasource en Weblogic para Universe u2?

Tags: weblogic

Cómo puedo configurar mi DataSource de weblogic para que acepte el controlador que usa Universe U2.

La clase es:

```
com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver
```

O bien, ¿necesito agregarlo?